# Android Layouts: Stick one Layout to the top of the screen and place another Layout centred below

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on my first android-project, a memory-game in Android Studio. The gameActivity-Frame should contain some textViews, displayed in one line (for stats) on the top of the screen and the memory-cards below. There are mutliple memory-versions, so the number of memory-cards vary - and by that the dimension of thier GridLayout.

My main Layout is a LinearLayout (vertical). I placed another LinearLayout (horizontal) on it, where the Textviews take place. To display the cards, I used a GridLayout which will be filled with cards once the game started.
The LinearLayout (with textViews) should always stick on the top of the screen. The GridLayout should be centered in the remaining space below.

What I get is that both Layouts either stick in the middle, or that the LinearLayout is correct, but the GridLayout is either on the bottom or on the top of the remaining space.

I tried to find a solution here on SO, and I think I tried every possible combination of the `gravity`- and `layout_gravity` - settings of the components. I can imagine the problem is that I can use either `wrap_content` or `match_parent` in the main Layout, but not both. Guess I'd need `wrap_content` to stick the first Layout to the top and `match_parent` to use the whole space below this Layout.

How can I stick the first Layout to the top and center the GridLayout in the remaining space?

The picture shows my current layout (see code below) and how I want it to look.
[center_GridLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWTyV.png)

**Edit to clarify:
The LinearLayout should stick to the top of the screen, the GridLayout should be
centered in the *remaining* space below the LinearLayout.
RelativeLayout won't do the job properly, because the layouts might overlap, depending on the amount of memory-cards and the user's device's dimensions.
I uploaded another screenshot where it's better visible what I want to achieve:**

[image: editToClarify]

This is my .xml (deleted some unimportant textViews):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MemoryLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStatsPairs"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/textStatsPairs" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayoutMainActivityTEST"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        tools:context=".GameActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [relative layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) or [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MemoryLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStatsPairs"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/textStatsPairs" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayoutMainActivityTEST"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        tools:context=".GameActivity" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly it does not fix my problem. I think I was not clear enough. The GridLayout should not centered in the whole screen, only in the remaining space below the LinearLayout. I edited my question and added another screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **relative layout along with linearlayout.From your question i got that you want your linearlayout always stick to top and GridLayout always stick to center**.If this is the case then i think following code snippet will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

   </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Texts Here"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ConstraintLayout was what fixed my problem... Here's the solution that finally works perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/memory_activity_4x4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_4x4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStatsPairs"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/textStatsPairs" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout4x4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout_4x4"
        tools:context=".GameActivity" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```